# How do you get roles with certain claims?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, roles

There is a method to get a list of users with a given claim with `userManager.GetUsersForClaimAsync`, however this does not retrieve those who have it indirectly, via a role. How can I do that? There isn't an equivalent method for the role manager, only a `roleManager.GetClaimsAsync`, which is only for an already loaded role.

`IdentityRole` (which I inherit from), does not have a `Claims` navigation property, so I can't query that way. I add the collection as follows:

```
public virtual ICollection<IdentityRoleClaim<string>> Claims { get; set; }
```

That just results in an "Invalid column name 'ApplicationRoleId'" when try to query. How do you define what foreign key to use when defining a collection? The `ForeignKey` attribute does not do anything and I can't see a way to set it using the model builder (`builder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().Navigation (r => r.Claims)`.

Comment: Hi @SamWM, did you try:`await _context.Roles.Include(r => r.RoleClaims).ToListAsync();
`?This code could get all the roles with claims.

Comment: `RoleClaims` or any collections are not part of `IdentityRole` or `IdentityRole<TKey>`. They were removed in 2.0 and later.